# Increasing Docker partition size on Google Cloud Compute instance running container image

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have an Apache server in production that is running in a Docker container, which I've deployed to a Google Compute instance using the ["gcloud compute instances create-with-container"](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create-with-container) command. The `/var/www/html` folder is mounted onto the container from the boot disk of the computer instance to make it persistent, using the `--container-mount-host-path` flag:

```
gcloud compute instances create-with-container $INSTANCE_NAME \
    --zone=europe-north1-a \
    --container-image gcr.io/my-project/my-image:latest \
    --container-mount-host-path mount-path=/var/www/html,host-path=/var/www/html,mode=rw \
    --machine-type="$MACHINE_TYPE"
```

But now I've ran into the problem that the size of the Docker partition is only 5.7G!
Output of `df -h`:

```
...
/dev/sda1       5.7G  3.6G  2.2G  62% /mnt/stateful_partition
overlay         5.7G  3.6G  2.2G  62% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/4f223d8157033ce937a79af741df3eadf79a02d2d003f01a085301ff66884bf2/merged
overlay         5.7G  3.6G  2.2G  62% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/86316491e2bb20bc300c1cc55c9f9254001ed77d6ec7f05f716af1e52fe15f53/merged
...
```

I had assumed that the partition size would increase automatically, but I ran into the problem where the website couldn't write files onto disk anymore because the partition was full. As a quick fix, I ran "docker prune -a" (there were a bunch of old images hanging around) on the host machine to make some more space on the docker partition.

So my question is, what is the proper way of increasing the size of the partition?

Comment: I now realize that I'm also unsure what the relationship between the `container-mount-host-path`,`/mnt/stateful_partition` and the docker `overlay` mounts are. So I'm unsure where the problem lies, in the writing into the "container-mount-host-path" or in the size of the partition or the overlay? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You do not have a problem unless you are running out of space. The 5.7 GB is the amount of free space in the host operating system which is /dev/sda1 in your case. My answer shows you how to create an instance with a larger file system which means a larger /dev/sda1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resize the boot disk in the Google Cloud Console GUI. However, since this is a container host, I recommend deleting the virtual machine instance and creating a new instance with the correct configuration.

The default disk size is usually 10 GB. To create a virtual machine instance with a larger disk, specify that when creating the instance.

Add the following to your CLI command:

```
--boot-disk-size=32GB
```

Optionally specify the type of persistent disk to control costs:

```
--boot-disk-type=pd-standard
```

[gcloud compute instances create-with-container](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create-with-container)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I would have assumed that the `--boot-disk-size` flag would only affect the size of the Compute instance's boot disk, not the size of the Docker container's mount? Or will the container's mount keep growing if the instance disk is larger?

Comment: @OskarKoli Please clarify what you mean by container's mount. Containers are stored in the host's file system. When you mount a path with **--container-mount-host-path** you control where in the host file system the mount is attached. In your example, you are mounting from the root file system, which sits on /dev/sda1. If you mean the **overlays** those are virtual file systems that map to layers in the container which again is stored on the root file system. My answer allows you to create a larger boot disk which means a large root file system which means more space for the containers.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing question, it's caused by my general confusion on on this issue! But your further clarification in the comment helped, I think I understand the logic better now. I'll take your advice and resize the disk and see where that takes me :)