# DiskPressure in Kubernetes nodes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a Kubernetes cluster deployed in `google cloud` with several deployments. The problem is that now I'm trying to apply new deployments and I'm having a trouble because almost all the pods deployed gives `DiskPressure` error because of low space in this path:`/mnt/stateful_partition`.

There is any way to increase this partition? The problem I've seen is that the filesystem is read-only so I cannot free up space deleting some logs or something like that... I'm completely blocked with that..

Any idea?

Comment: Possible candidate for serverfault.com

Comment: Does comments in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69794582/increasing-docker-partition-size-on-google-cloud-compute-instance-running-contai help?

Answer (score 0):

First check in the logging if you can see the error message `(combined from similar events): Failed to garbage collect required amount of images. Attempted to free 9041880678 bytes, but only found 0 bytes eligible to free.` 
if so, then this message comes from [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.18/pkg/kubelet/images/image_gc_manager.go#L312),indicating that the Kubelet failed to remove the unused images. This could happen if any one of the following conditions is met:

- The image must not currently be in use by an existing container running on the node
- The image must not have been recently pulled (to avoid thrashing), etc.
- Only images that are "eligible" to be removed are actually garbage collected and end up being deleted.

As mentioned in this [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/node-pressure-eviction/#node-conditions:%7E:text=an%20eviction%20threshold-,DiskPressure,-nodefs.available%2C), the Node condition 'DiskPressure' implies that available disk space and inodes on either the node's root filesystem or image filesystem have met an eviction threshold.

You may follow the suggestion mentioned [here](https://www.airplane.dev/blog/kubernetes-disk-pressure).